# Adding RAID 0 disks to a system previously setup as AHCI

Tags: raid, sata, ahci

I'm running Windows 10 Pro on an AMD 5900X system with X570 motherboard. Windows was installed on an NVMe SSD (Samsung 980 Pro) and then two other SATA drives for data. Motherboard set to AHCI from the outset.

I now wish to add 2 new drives for data in a motherboard raid 0 config and keep the pre-existing drives accessible. When I install these and switch motherboard SATA setting from AHCI to RAID, Windows boots fine (NVMe drive unaffected by the switch) but the two pre-existing drives are no longer visible to it.

I have tried making the change to RAID and then booting into safe mode (with bcdedit) to try and trigger a switch from AHCI to RAID drivers - no luck.

Have confirmed that all drives (new and old) are visible to Windows in AHCI mode. I am specifically looking for motherboard RAID 1 rather than a Storage Spaces solution.
Grateful for any advice.

Comment: Are the disks visible in the RAID controller's management tools? Are the RAID drivers _installed_ at all? While AHCI is standard, the RAID controller (if there is one) will need its specific drivers to be installed... (However, all the bcdedit stuff only applies to the volume that the OS is booting from. For data disks, those just work like regular drivers since there's no need to "early load" them.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @user1686 - I figured it out.

1. connect the new disks
2. set motherboard to RAID in bios
3. install AMD RAID drivers and s/w in Windows (<-- had to happen after
   2. above otherwise would not install correctly)
4. setup RAID array in AMD s/w in Windows
5. initialise and format new disks in Disk Management
6. go to superuser and post the answer